# How to store string from an array of strings in to a variable in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
 char movie[15];
 char movielist[25][30]={"thalaiva","aruvi","sarkar","visvasam","veeram","mersal","bigil","kaithi","mahanadhi","papanasam","vishwaroopam","padayappa","thadam","indian","petta","kaala","psycho","comali","bahubali","saaho","enthiran","vettai","asuraguru","penguin","cocktai"};
 movie=movielist[rand()%25];
 printf("%s",movie);

}
```

I want the variable movie to store any random string from the array movielist!
The code above gives me error.
main.c:8:7: error: assignment to expression with array type
movie=movielist[rand()%25];

Comment: What is your "segmentation error"? I got compilation error.

Comment: If you want to make a copy use `strcpy` not assignment as that is not how you copy a string. If you just want to reference the original string then use a char pointer (`char *`).

Comment: Also you may want to see [c - srand() — why call it only once? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Comment: Unless you are programming in a *freestanding environment* (without the benefit of any OS), in a standards conforming implementation, the allowable declarations for `main` for are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char *argv[])` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char **argv`).  See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Comment: Avoid the use of the ancient DOS header `conio.h`, that makes your code 100% non-portable. (you don't use anything from that header in your code above) You can use `getchar()` to hold the terminal window open on windows, instead of `getch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use char pointer instead of char array:

```
char *movie;  // instead of char movie[15];
...
movie = movielist[rand() % 25];
```

If you use `movie[15]` as you did, you can't assign it to individual item in the `movielist` as assignment operator does not work with array.

Comment: Note, you should use `const char *movie;` to make clear what `movie` points to is immutable. (compared to a mutable result provided by @MikeCAT)

Comment: Also understand using a pointer does not store a string from your array, it simply holds the address to an existing element within the array.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has two main issues.

#### 1.

With

```
movie = movielist[rand() % 25];
```

you attempt to assign `movie`(an array of 15 `char`, type `char [15]`) by a pointer to an array of 30 `char` (type `char (*)[30]`). This is not permissible in C. You cannot assign arrays.

Since you don't want to modify/change the movie titles/strings in the program, you don't need a two-dimensional array for `movielist` and an array for `movie`.

Use an array of pointer for `movielist` which point to string literals and a pointer for `movie` instead.

The pointer `move` you assign then by the value of one of the pointers in `movielist`.

---

#### 2.

`rand()` needs a seed with `srand()`. Without that, `rand()` won't work properly. But you forgot that in your code.

A usual way is to provide a seed dependent upon the CPU clock time.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>       // for the time seed.

int main (void)
{
   char const * movie;
   char const * const movielist[] = { 
                                       "thalaiva","aruvi","sarkar","visvasam","veeram",
                                       "mersal","bigil","kaithi","mahanadhi","papanasam",
                                       "vishwaroopam","padayappa","thadam","indian",
                                       "petta","kaala","psycho","comali","bahubali",
                                       "saaho","enthiran","vettai","asuraguru","penguin",
                                       "cocktai"
                                    };

   // initialize random seed.
   srand(time(NULL));

   movie = movielist[rand() % 25];

   printf("%s", movie);
}
```

---

Side note:

- `void main()` is not compliant to the C standard. Use `int main (void)`.

Comment: Thanx  a lot for your explanation :) @RobertS supports Monica Cellio

Comment: @sowmicaML I'm glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) for copying strings.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
 char movie[30];
 char movielist[25][30]={"thalaiva","aruvi","sarkar","visvasam","veeram","mersal","bigil","kaithi","mahanadhi","papanasam","vishwaroopam","padayappa","thadam","indian","petta","kaala","psycho","comali","bahubali","saaho","enthiran","vettai","asuraguru","penguin","cocktai"};
 strcpy(movie,movielist[rand()%25]);
 printf("%s",movie);

}
```